# `\titletoc`, formatting `\dottedcontents`: color of chapter number

Tags: table-of-contents, color, titletoc

After much playing around I have encountered an issue with only setting the `\thechapter` number in color, when using `titletoc` and `\dottedcontents`. I achieve the following, but as you can tell the chapter number is repeated. Is there a way to call onto `\thecontentslabel` in such a way as to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
   \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{239, 0, 0}
   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,200}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpages}{xcolor}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\large\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\color{myred} \thecontentslabel]{1.5em}}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}

\dottedcontents{chapter}[2em]{\large\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[{\color{myblue}\thecontentslabel}]{2em}}{}



\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
    \part{Trial name of Part}
    this is a blind text

    \chapter{Trial chapter}
    this is more blind text

    \section{Trial section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a misuse of `\dottedcontents` , with same syntax as `\titlecontents`. Here is a solution with the latter command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[newparttoc] {titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Huge\fontsize{30pt}{60pt}\filcenter}{\partname{} \color{myred}\thepart}{0em}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, pdfpages]{xcolor}
   \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{239, 0, 0}
   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,200}
\titlecontents{part}[2.2em]{\Large\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\color{myred} \thecontentslabel]{1.35em}}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{1ex}]
%
\titlecontents{chapter}[2.2em]{\large\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[{\color{myblue}\thecontentslabel}]{1em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{0.6ex}]
%
\titlecontents{section}[2.83em]{}
{\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}]{1.9em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{0.6ex}]

\begin{document}\setcounter{part}{3}
 \tableofcontents
    \part{Trial name of Part}
    this is a blind text

    \chapter{Trial chapter}
    this is more blind text

    \section{Trial section}

\end{document} [1.5em]
```

[image]

Comment: Thak you; Is there a syntax that would fix my issue with `\dottedcontents`? I am trying to understand why it would not be possible to just change the number and leave everything else as is

Comment: Unfortunately,  `dottedcontents` has no way  to format the label. You only give can  enter commands for global formatting of entries (this means that if you type `\color{blue}`, the label and the section title will be  blue).

Comment: Thank you for that. So to clarify, the `\thecontentslabel` then refers to the entire entry, rather than just the `\chapter` number?

Comment: Not at all. It contains just the chapter (or section or…) number. The first mandatory argument of `\dottedcontents` as well as `\titlecontents` is for the global formatting. But the  second mandatory argument of `\dottedcontents` is the label width, whereas the second of `\titlecontents` is for the formatting of the entry (for numbered entries),in which you can use the `\contentslabel` command to format the label, the rest  acting on the title. The third argument is for the formatting of unnumbered chapters, sections, &c.